# MS bookings not working anymore inside WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, office365

I have a WKWebView in an iOS app using SwiftUI which loads a Microsft bookings web page (I have tested this with multiple booking pages and it happens with any public booking page). This was working until now, MS bookings now displays an error page with a generic error "Something went wrong" and a button to refresh the page (when clicking on this button a sigin page appears). In a Webview on Android or in a 'regular' browser everything works fine. The code looks like this:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let request: URLRequest
    let options: Options

    private var navDelegate: WKNavigationDelegate
    private var scrollDelegate: UIScrollViewDelegate
    
    init(
        request: URLRequest,
        options: Options = Options()
    ) {
        self.request = request
        self.content = nil
        self.options = options
        self.navDelegate = WVNavigationDelegate()
        self.scrollDelegate = WVUIScrollViewDelegate(scrollEnabled: options.scrollEnabled)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {
        let wv = WKWebView()

        wv.navigationDelegate = navDelegate
        wv.scrollView.delegate = scrollDelegate
        
        // Seems to make no difference
        if #available(iOS 15.4, *) {
            wv.configuration.preferences.isSiteSpecificQuirksModeEnabled = true
        }
        
        return wv
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.load(req)   
        uiView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = options.scrollEnabled
    }
    
    struct Options {
        var scrollEnabled: Bool = true
        var zoomEnabled: Bool = true
    }
    
}

class WVUIScrollViewDelegate: NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    let scrollEnabled: Bool
    
    init(scrollEnabled: Bool) {
        self.scrollEnabled = scrollEnabled
    }
    
    func scrollViewWillBeginZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, with view: UIView?) {
        scrollView.pinchGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = scrollEnabled
    }
}

class WVNavigationDelegate: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
    
    // Test to check if cookies were the issue but didn't make any difference
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {
        
        guard let response = navigationResponse.response as? HTTPURLResponse, let url = navigationResponse.response.url else {
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
            return
        }

        if let headerFields = response.allHeaderFields as? [String: String] {

            let cookies = HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: headerFields, for: url)
            cookies.forEach { cookie in
                webView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.setCookie(cookie)
                HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(cookie)
            }
        }

        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
    
}
```

In the `WVNavigationDelegate` I also have a js script injected in the webview to intercept a specific call needed to detect when the booking is made but I left i out for simplicity since the problem also occurs without this code.

Are there other functionalities like the cookies I have to configure since those pages are working in Android WebViews and other browsers?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue. Occurred around the same time.

Other people having similar issues: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1195010/ios-webkit-wkwebview-is-not-supported-to-access-th

My workaround, until there is a solution, is to open this specific URL with the installed default browser **outside the app** and dismiss the WebView sheet therefore.

Workaround Code looks like this:

```swift
 if let bookingURL = navigationAction.request.url,
           bookingURL.host == "outlook.office365.com" {
            closeFunction?() // dismiss WebView-Sheet
            UIApplication.shared.open(bookingURL)
        }
```

If I have a better or real solution, I will post it here.